# incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s) inferred: Dao<Account,String> upper bound(s)

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm implementing ORMLite on an existing database on my Android Studio Project... All is done, but now i'm working on upgrades, si I work with the DAO but I get this error:

> Error:(67, 68) error: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
>   inferred: Dao
>   upper bound(s): Dao,Dao
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = ...;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "...";
    public SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private Context mContext;
    Dao<Account, String> daoDemandes;



    private static final String TABLE_DEMANDES = "demandes";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_XML_SENDLEAD = "xmlSendLead";
    private static final String KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SENDLEAD = "statutEnvoieSendLead";
    private static final String KEY_DATEENVOIE_SENDLEAD = "dateEnvoieSendLead";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACTWEBID = "contactWebId";
    private static final String KEY_XML_SIMULATION = "xmlSimulation";
    private static final String KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SIMULATION = "statutEnvoieSimulation";
    private static final String KEY_DATEENVOIE_SIMULATION = "dateEnvoieSimulation";



    private Dao<Demandes, Integer> simpleDao = null;
    private RuntimeExceptionDao<Demandes, Integer> simpleRuntimeDao = null;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource){
        try {
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Demandes.class);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {

            Dao<Account, String> daoDemandes = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Demandes.class);


            if (oldVersion < 4) {
                daoDemandes.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_DEMANDES + " RENAME TO demandes2");
                daoDemandes.executeRaw("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DEMANDES + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_XML_SENDLEAD + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SENDLEAD + " INTEGER," + KEY_DATEENVOIE_SENDLEAD + " DATETIME," + KEY_CONTACTWEBID + " INTEGER," + KEY_XML_SIMULATION + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SIMULATION + " INTEGER," + KEY_DATEENVOIE_SIMULATION + " DATETIME" + ")");
                daoDemandes.executeRaw("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_DEMANDES + " (" + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_XML_SENDLEAD + "," + KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SENDLEAD + "," + KEY_DATEENVOIE_SENDLEAD + ")" + " SELECT id, xml, statutEnvoie, dateEnvoie" + " FROM demandes2;");
                daoDemandes.executeRaw("DROP TABLE demandes2");
                System.out.println("v4 parsed");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  Dao<Account, String> daoDemandes = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Demandes.class);
> ```

You are trying to create a `Dao<Account,String>` but you are creating a DAO for the class `Demandes`.  That should be:

```
Dao<Demandes, String> daoDemandes = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Demandes.class);
```

The `String` in there should be the id type of `Demandes` which could be a `Long` or `Integer`.

You should have been able to figured this problem out by yourself.  Maybe you need to learn more about [how generics work](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)?  When debugging code, you should be able to evaluate the problem by looking closely at the line that caused the exception.

Another thing to try would be to have removed the type specification from before `daoDemandes` and allow your IDE to self generate it.  That would have worked.